# BCP Utility Unable to Export Data in Linux Using JAVA:

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, linux, bcp

I tried to execute the following piece of code to export data(myFileName.csv) :

```
bcp "select * from DataBase.schema.TABLE_NAME" queryout tableData.csv -c -t, , -S [server] -U [user] -P '[password(with special characters)]' > LogFile.txt
```

the above code is **working fine in terminal**.

In contrast, I tried the same piece of code using java.

```
File dir = new File("Mydirectory");
    Path dataPath = Paths.get("tableData.csv");
    List<String> val = new ArrayList();
    val.add("bcp");
    val.add("\"select * from " + [Database] + ".[Schema]." + table_name + "\"");
    val.add("queryout");
    val.add(dataPath.toString());
    val.add("-c");
    val.add("-t");
    val.add(",");
    val.add("-S");
    val.add([server]);// ex: if Server is 10.0.0.1  then val.add("10.0.0.1");
    val.add("-U");
    val.add([user]); // ex: if User_name is TestA then val.add("TestA");
    val.add("-P");
    val.add([password(with special characters)]); // ex: if Password is !@#MyPassword*& then val.add("!@#MyPassword*&");
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(val);
    File logFile = new File("LogFile.txt");
    System.out.println("BCP command :" + builder.command());
    builder.redirectlogFile(logFile);
    builder.directory(dir);
    Process exec = builder.start();
    System.out.println("BCP process completed : with errors :" + exec.waitFor());
    System.out.println("BCP logFile :" + org.​apache.​commons.​io.FileUtils.readFileToString(logFile));
```

I got the following error:

> BCP command :[bcp, "select * from DataBase.schema.TABLE_NAME",
>   queryout,tableData.csv, -c, -t, ,, -S, 10.0.0.1, -U, TestA, -P,
>   !@#MyPassword*&]
>
> BCP process completed : with errors :1
>
> BCP logFile : Starting copy... SQLState = S1000, NativeError = 0 Error
>   = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Unable to resolve column level collations
>
> SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 102 Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server
>   Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near 'select * from
>   DataBase.schema.TABLE_NAME'.

By looking the error I checked the collations of `Server`, `Database` and `Table` all seems similar **SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS**

### System Specifications :

```
Linux :
    uname -mrs
        Linux 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 x86_64
    uname -a
        Linux [domain] 3.10.0-327.10.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Feb 16 17:03:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
    cat /etc/redhat-release
        CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

ODBC Driver for linux:
    isql --version
        unixODBC 2.3.0

    odbcinst -q -d -n "SQL Server Native Client 11.0"
        [SQL Server Native Client 11.0]
        Description=Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver V1.0 for Linux
        Driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
```

Any anyone help me What i am doing wrong over here.

Comment: Have you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383511/bcp-fails-to-export-with-error-unable-to-resolve-column-level-collation

Comment: Have you tried it with windows machine?

Comment: @ali786 - Yes I tried in windows, Its working perfectly. Also here I am not using any `ORM` between `BCP` and `MSSQL`.

Comment: The `ProcessBuilder` inserts a comma between every array entry resulting in too many commas and the syntax error you see.  Change your code to remove the extra commas.  Try using a `StringBuilder` to build the command string.

Comment: @quest4truth Commas between the elements of array or arraylist is because of 'toString ()' method. Those commas are not executed as command in "Process Builder".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried by creating shell script 
its working fine.

```
File dir = new File("Mydirectory"); 
Path dataPath = Paths.get("tableData.csv"); 
SStringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
strb.append("bcp ");
strb.append("\"select " + column + "  from " + credentials.getSchema() + ".dbo." + table_name + "\" ");
strb.append("queryout ");
strb.append(dataPath.toString());
strb.append(" -c ");
strb.append("-t ");
strb.append(", ");
strb.append("-S ");
strb.append(credentials.getServer());
strb.append(" -U ");
strb.append(credentials.getUser());
strb.append(" -P ");
strb.append(credentials.getPassword());

File shellFile = new File(folderName + File.separator + "exec.sh");

try (FileOutputStream outShell = new FileOutputStream(shellFile)) {
    outShell.write(strb.toString().getBytes());
    outShell.flush();
}
shellFile.setExecutable(true, false);
shellFile.setWritable(true, false);
shellFile.setReadable(true, false);
builder = new ProcessBuilder(shellFile.getAbsolutePath());

File logFile = new File("LogFile.txt");
System.out.println("BCP command :" + builder.command());
builder.redirectlogFile(logFile); builder.directory(dir); 
Process exec = builder.start();
System.out.println("BCP process completed : with errors :" + exec.waitFor());
System.out.println("BCP logFile :" + org.​apache.​commons.​io.FileUtils.readFileToString(logFile));
```

Thanks to All...

Answer (score 3):

I want to share with you some suggestions. You may have try. Hope it will solve your issue.

### Suggestion-1:

Sometimes this problem occurs if we change collation of column or make any changes of table/view own properties. **One thing you could do is to check the collation setting of columns b\w source & destination table and then use COLLATE clause in your source script to change the collation to match that of destination.** This problem can be solved by recreating the table/view. So I will suggest you to again create the `"TABLE_NAME"` from your `"DataBase.schema"`

### Suggestion-2:

> **Recommended solution:**

Sometimes queryout is not worked and gives error. On that case, if we use print then this problem is solved.
You can go through this section: [SQL query using bcp not working with queryout as a variable](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1030492-sql-query-using-bcp-not-working-with-queryout-as-a-variable)

### Suggestion-3:

> Tough task but useful:

You may try to remote connect to the server and run the `bcp` without the `-S` option from your code. **Remove the below portion and make a try**:

```
val.add("-S");
val.add([server]);// ex: if Server is 10.0.0.1  then val.add("10.0.0.1");
```

If the server collation is different from the database or column collation, try to create the format file and explicitly specify it in the bcp.

### Suggestion-4:

Sometimes `null` and `bulk insert` may also cause this problem. you can go through:
[Bulk Insert Collation Error](http://www.dbforums.com/showthread.php?514834-Bulk-Insert-Collation-Error)

### Suggestion-5:

This problem was occurred in `SQL Server 2005 Native Client`. But microsoft will not fix this in previous version. They have fixed it in `SQL Server 2008 Native Client`. For more details you can go through: 
[BCP Error - Unable to resolve column level collations - by krishnc](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/274313/bcp-error-unable-to-resolve-column-level-collations)

Answer (score 1):

Use `freebcp` command from Linux syntax are all most same as `BCP`.

Ie

```
bcp mydatabase.dbo.mytable out mytable.csv /U myusername /P mypassword /S myhost /c
```

is equivalent to

```
freebcp mydatabase.dbo.mytable out mytable.csv -U myusername -P mypassword -S myhost -c
```

Comment: 'freebcp' in the sense your meaning the 'FreeTDS' or 'bcp' intern supports 'freebcp ' in Linux server.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/1/freebcp   http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/freebcp.1.html

Comment: In last project i have used on mac .

Answer (score 1):

`ProcessBuilder` doesn't have the same behavior as CMD, so you don't need quotes:

```
val.add("select * from " + database_name + ".[Schema]." + table_name);
```